# Let $N$ be a normal subgroup of index $m$ in $G$. Prove that $a^m \in N$ for all $a \in G$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

I'm trying to understand this proof:

> Let $N$ be a normal subgroup of index $m$ in $G$. Prove that $a^m \in
> > N$ for all $a \in G$.
>   **Proof** $\;\;$ Let $a\in G$. Since $[G:N]=m$, then $|G/N|=m$. From Lagrange's Theorem, it follows that $(aN)^m=a^mN=eN=N$. Hence $a^m  \in
>  N$.

I don't understand why $a^mN=eN$. Can anybody help me out ?

Comment: The order of $aN$ divides $m$. So $(aN)^m=eN$. But it turns out that $(aN)^m=a^mN$.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

$m$ is the order of the quotient group $G/N$, $aN$ is an element of that group.
What happens when you raise an element to the order of a group? What is the identity element of the group $G/N$?

Comment: aah of course! so you could write:
$$N=eN=(aN)^{|G/N|}=(aN)^m=a^mN$$

Therefore $a^m \in N$

Comment: @Kasper yes, exactly!

Answer (score 3):

It follows from Lagrange's theorem, since the order of the quotient group $G/N$ is $m$. Therefore, any element of $G/N$ (all of which are of the form $aN$ for some $a\in G$) satisfies $\left(aN\right)^m = e_{G/N} = eN = N$. We also know that to compute a product $kNhN$ in a quotient group $G/N$, we can simply look at the product of the representatives $k$ and $h$ and the product $kNhN$ will be $khN$. Therefore, we have $e_{G/N} = eN = N = \left(aN\right)^m = a^m N$, so $a^m\in N$.