# Providing counterexample

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, permutations, normal-subgroups

I bumped on the [following](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/361708/let-n-be-a-normal-subgroup-of-index-m-in-g-prove-that-am-in-n-for-all) question.

> Let $N$ be a normal subgroup of index $m$ in $G$. Prove that $a^m \in
>  N$ for all $a \in G$.
>   **Proof** $\;\;$ Let $a\in G$. Since $[G:N]=m$, then $|G/N|=m$. From Lagrange's Theorem, it follows that $(aN)^m=a^mN=eN=N$. Hence $a^m  \in
>  N$.

I'm trying to provide an example that this statement is true only if $N$
 is normal. Usually such examples can be easily found in $S_n$, but this time my attempts were unsuccessful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

consider the subgroup $\{e,(1,2)\}\subseteq S_3$, it has index $3$. And $(2,3)^3=(2,3)\not \in \{e,(1,2)\}$