# Infinite case: Let $N$ be a normal subgroup of index m in $G$. Prove that $a^{m}\in N$ for all $a\in G$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, normal-subgroups, infinite-groups

I was reading this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/361708/let-n-be-a-normal-subgroup-of-index-m-in-g-prove-that-am-in-n-for-all):

> Let $N$ be a normal subgroup of index $m$. Prove that $a^{m}\in N$ for all $a\in G$.
>
> **Proof:** Let $a \in G$. Since $[G:N] = m$, then $|G/N|=m$. From Lagrange's Theorem, it follows that $(aN)^m=a^mN=eN=N$. Hence $a^m\in N$.

For $|G/N|=m$ to follow from $[G:N]=m$, both $G$ and $N$ must be of finite order. But this assumption is not specified in the problem.

Is it possible to prove the same when $G$ and $N$ are of infinite order?

For example:
Let us take $\mathbb{Z}$ under addition and $n\mathbb{Z}$ as a group and normal subgroup of infinite order. Then $[\mathbb{Z}:n\mathbb{Z}] = n$, so following the problem hypothesis, $x^n= nx\in n\mathbb{Z}$.

The problem statement seems to hold on that example. If the problem does not hold on the infinite example, how can I find a counterexample?

Comment: $|G/N|$ means the size (order) of the quotient group.

Comment: You need them to be finite to say $[G:N]=|G|/|N|$, but $[G:N]=|G/N|$ holds by definition of the index essentially. This is sufficient for the problem since $G/N$ is a finite group, even though $G$ and $N$ may not be.

Comment: @FrenzyLi Yes! That's the question!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$G/N$ is the quotient group of $G$ mod $N$, where $N$ is a normal subgroup in $G$.  The elements in $G/N$ are exactly the cosets of $N$ in $G$, so $|G/N|=[G:N]$.  Given $[G:N]=m$, we know that $|G/N|=m$.

Note that $|G/N|$ is not $|G|/|N|$ unless both $G$ and $N$ are finite.  The proof only cares that the quotient group $G/N$ is finite and doesn't really care if $G$ or $N$ are finite.

In your particular example, the quotient group $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z} = \left\{n\mathbb{Z},n\mathbb{Z}+1,\ldots,n\mathbb{Z}+(n-1)\right\}$ is finite.

Comment: Thanks, I had not understood that $[G:N]=m$ means that $|G/N|=m$ so that the quotient group is finite and then we can use Lagrange's theorem